# Angular 8: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ws' (Puppeteer)

Tags: puppeteer, angular8

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ws' in '...project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib'
```

I'm trying to use puppeteer but when I execute the project it shows me that error, I'm using Angular 8 without webpack.

I ran this, but it did not change anything.
npm install --save ws and npm install --save-dev @types/ws